# Is not null not eliminating nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

Can someone help and shed light as to why am i still getting nulls even though one of the conditions in a table joins specifies that alternative unit cannot be a null.

[image: Only one record should be displayed with no nulls]

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE when oplistm.unit_code = 'CASE'  then ROUND(oplistm.price / conv_factor,2)
when oplistm.unit_code = 'KG' then ROUND(oplistm.price * conv_factor,2)
WHEN oplistm.unit_code = 'EACH' and stu.converted_unit = 'KG' and stu.converted_unit is not null then ROUND(oplistm.price / conv_factor,2)
WHEN oplistm.unit_code = 'EACH' and stu.converted_unit = 'CASE' and stu.converted_unit is not null then ROUND(oplistm.price * conv_factor,2)
end as 'alternative unit price',
stu.converted_unit as 'alternative unit'



FROM sys030.scheme.oplistm oplistm (nolock) 
left join sys030.scheme.stockm stockm (nolock) on stockm.product = oplistm.product_code
LEFT join sys030.scheme.stunitpm as stu (nolock) on stu.product = oplistm.product_code  and stockm.warehouse = stu.warehouse and stu.base_name = stockm.unit_code and stu.converted_unit is not null
WHERE oplistm.product_code <>'LIC' and oplistm.product_code <> ''  and stockm.product = 'M-47-68-BR-02-XX'
```

Comment: The only `not null` clauses I find is inside the `case` expression, are you sure you handled all cases of nulls in there?

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation? Why are you grouping on columns that aren't even in your select? Why are you using `DISTINCT` when you have a `GROUP BY`? Why are you *spamming* that `NOLOCK` hint? You do understand what it does, right?

Comment: Simplify your question. I can't imagine so many tables and columns are required to illustrate the problem. [mcve]

Comment: It is absolutely possible as the `not null` condition is on a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: To add to the other comments: your `CASE` expression has no `ELSE` condition. Should none of the conditions be met, you yield a `NULL` value.

Comment: In truth, I was suggest that the problem is your understanding. There are so many problems with the syntax or the query and the fact the results is wrong is the least of your worries. Fix the query first. Fix the `JOINS`; they are *all* declared as a `LEFT JOIN`, but at least one is an implicit `INNER JOIN`. Remove the `NOLOCK` hints; you clearly don't understand the implications of using it; or if you did you would be changing the isolation level not spamming the hint. Fix the `GROUP BY`; is it needed when you aren't aggregating? Fix the `DISTINCT`; is it needed? Not if you are aggregating.

Comment: OK let me clarify as I got a little lazy with editing the code before pasting it in here.
I have now tidied up unnecessary groupings etc.  This is part of a larger query.
Condition i was referring to is contained in the JOIN clause.

and stu.converted_unit is not null

Comment: All of your case results are the same: `ROUND(ROUND(oplistm.price * conv_factor,2)2)` if `oplistm.price` or `conv_factor` is null, your answer is NULL

Comment: I'm sorry if the comments come across as patronising. I think there are a lot of important points in the comments that you might learn from. In fact there are other reasons your values are NULL beyond @Squirrel response. It's just that there isn't enough context to know which one of those reasons you would consider to be the answer.

Comment: _I am slowly learning_ You are also learning bad habits - which are difficult to unlearn and correct. But don't splatter your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere), don't use deprecated syntax for hints, and don't use hints without a **very good** reason.

Comment: Perhaps I am but since my boss insits on using NOLOCK than I can do squat about it. But thank you for pointing this out. And since many people use the reports produced with these queries. I suppose nolock might be in order. As on the other side people are constantly updating this data. And my understanding is, that this prevents query from getting stuck due to data being manipulated a the same time as query is being executed.

Comment: your query has LEFT JOIN which can return NULL when there is not Matching records with the Left table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this condition in the `on` clause of an outer join:

```
stu.converted_unit is not null
```

Although it does filter out `converted_unit` values that are `NULL`, the `LEFT JOIN` might just add them back in.

So, if you really need this condition, change the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s.  The first one is, in fact, effectively an `INNER JOIN` because of the `WHERE` clause.